# Pandas Multiindex columns slice: use combination of all and pesice selet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Input: hierarchical headered dataframe (multiindex columns).

Ask: select combination of specific column(s) `[level0, level1]` and broadcast `[level0, :]`

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B"], ["x", "y", "z"]])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8,6), columns=index)
```

The desire result is to select `('A','y')` and everything for `'B'`.
I've managed to achieve this using the solution below:

```
df[[x for x in df.columns if x == ('A','z') or x[0]=='B']]
```

I've tried to use `.loc[]` and `slice(None)` but this did not work.

Is there a more elegant solution to iterate over the columns' tuples?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your list comprehension should work:

```py
cols = [ent for ent in df if ent == ('A','y') or ent[0] == 'B']
df.loc[:, cols]
          A         B
          y         x         y         z
0  0.069915  2.563734  1.034784  0.659189
1 -0.240847  1.924626  1.241827  0.973155
2 -1.091353 -1.003005  1.648075 -1.162863
3 -0.747503 -0.211539  1.861991 -1.011261
4 -0.354648 -0.117533  0.524876  0.884997
5  0.786158 -2.073479  1.374893  1.428770
6  0.597740  0.853482 -0.187112  0.000626
7 -0.749839 -1.084576 -0.327888 -0.286908
```

Another option is with [select_columns](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select_columns) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.select_columns(('A','y'), 'B')
          A         B
          y         x         y         z
0  0.069915  2.563734  1.034784  0.659189
1 -0.240847  1.924626  1.241827  0.973155
2 -1.091353 -1.003005  1.648075 -1.162863
3 -0.747503 -0.211539  1.861991 -1.011261
4 -0.354648 -0.117533  0.524876  0.884997
5  0.786158 -2.073479  1.374893  1.428770
6  0.597740  0.853482 -0.187112  0.000626
7 -0.749839 -1.084576 -0.327888 -0.286908
```